# PHP Soap Complex Data Type?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume a PHP Soap service however I seem to have having trouble with a complex/abstract type.

This is the SOAP call generated using SOAP UI :-

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lin="http://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LineCharacteristicsWS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lin:GetLineCharacteristics>
         <lin:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <lin:UserCredentials>
               <!--Optional:-->

               <!--Optional:-->
               <lin:Username>testUser</lin:Username>
               <lin:Password>testPass</lin:Password><lin:AgentID>1234</lin:AgentID>
            </lin:UserCredentials>
            <lin:RequestDetails xsi:type="lin:TelephoneNumberRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <lin:TelephoneNumber>123456789</lin:TelephoneNumber>
            </lin:RequestDetails>
            <lin:UserConsent>Yes</lin:UserConsent>
            <lin:ServiceType>MPF</lin:ServiceType>
         </lin:request>
      </lin:GetLineCharacteristics>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my PHP code :-

```
$call = new StdClass();

$call->request =  new StdClass();
$call->request->UserConsent = "Yes";
$call->request->ServiceType = "MPF";

$call->request->UserCredentials =  new StdClass();
$call->request->UserCredentials->Username="testUser";
$call->request->UserCredentials->Password="testPass";
$call->request->UserCredentials->AgentID=1234;


$call->request->RequestDetails = new StdClass();
$call->request->RequestDetails->TelephoneNumber = "123456789";

$url = "https://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LineCharacteristicsWSV6/LineCharacteristicsWS.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1, exceptions=> 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));

$result = $client->GetLineCharacteristics($call);

echo $client->__getLastRequest();
echo $client->__getLastResponse();
```

When I run the code, the following error is generated :-

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 382). ---> The specified type is abstract: name='RequestType', namespace='http://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LineCharacteristicsWS', at http://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LineCharacteristicsWS'>. in /Users/jamesormerod/NetBeansProjects/fpdfDev/TestClass.php:23

Can anyone help?

Comment: try `$request->TelephoneNumberRequest->TelephoneNumber`

Comment: No, I believe it requires some kind of class map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to send the request well formed with correct type and namespace, you must use both classes named as the required elements and a classmap that maps the elements to the classes.
The [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) project can help you generate the classes and the classmap. You can use the project at [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com/).

Then if for example you generate the package with the name `LineCharacteristics`, you'll be able to send the request using this sample code:

`$lineCharacteristicsServiceGet = new LineCharacteristicsServiceGet();
// sample call for LineCharacteristicsServiceGet::GetLineCharacteristics()
$details = new LineCharacteristicsStructTelephoneNumberRequest('+3363136363636');
$request = new LineCharacteristicsStructGetLineCharacteristicsRequest($details, LineCharacteristicsEnumUserConsentEnum::VALUE_YES, LineCharacteristicsEnumServiceTypeEnum::VALUE_MPF);
$userCredentials = new LineCharacteristicsStructCredentials(11111,'********','********');
$request->setUserCredentials($userCredentials);
$characteristics = new LineCharacteristicsStructGetLineCharacteristics($request);
$r = $lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->GetLineCharacteristics($characteristics);
echo implode("\r\n", array($lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getLastRequestHeaders(),$lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getLastRequest(),$lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getLastResponseHeaders(),$lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getLastResponse())); 
if($r)
    print_r($lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getResult());
else
    print_r($lineCharacteristicsServiceGet->getLastError());`